# Rails Query with nested association and group ( by associated object)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Given this model relationships:

```
orders.rb
belongs_to user

user.rb
belongs_to company

company.rb
has_many users
```

I wanted to count all orders made by each company, so I got this:

```
Order.joins(user: :company)
.group(['companies.name, companies.id])
.count
```

and the result is

["Company 1", 1] => 123

BUT I don't know how to change this query to have

```
<Company id: 1,name: "Jim Beam"> => 5
```

instead of array of Company's attributes.

Comment: Do you have different companies with the same name ? (i'm trying to understand why you need to group on name and id)

Comment: @Joel_Blum , No I don't have. I just want to have as result of this query a hash with id and name, because later on it will be easier and much more readable to get some value from such structure instead of getting to values via index of array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be made easier by adding another association to the model:

```
# company.rb
has_many :users
has_many :orders, through: :users
```

Then you can do this:

```
   companies = Company.
               joins(:orders).
               group("company.id").
               select("company.id, company.name, count(orders.id) as orders_count")
```

if you then say `companies.first` you will see something like this:

```
#<Company:0x005610fa35e678 id: 15 name: 'foo'>
```

it doesn't look like the `orders_count` is there. But it actually has been loaded already. You can get at it like this:

```
companies.first.orders_count
```

You can also see it if you convert the company to a hash:

```
companies.first.attributes # => { id: 15, orders_count: 2, name: "foo" }
```

In Postgres at least, if you want to get more data in the attributes hash you have to individually specify each of the columns in the `select` string. I'm not sure about other databases.